# matlab to c code generation workflow

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

am testing matlab to c/c++ code for my school project and i dont know how to use the generated c/c++ code and static library inside visual studio,
my matlab function is as simple as

```
function c = simpleProduct(a,b) %#codegen
c=a*b;
```

and i used matlab coder to generate c/c++ code(static library) for my win32 project but the thing is it generated a lot of files other than what am looking for
which was simpleproduct.c, simpleproduct.h , simpleproduct.lib but instead i get this.

```
rt_nonfinite.h
rtGetInf.h
rtGetNaN.h
rtwtypes.h
simpleProduct_types.h
rt_nonfinite.cpp
rtGetInf.cpp     
rtGetNaN.cpp
rtwtypes.cpp
simpleProduct.obj 
rt_nonfinite.obj 
rtGetNaN.obj 
rtGetInf.obj 
simpleProduct_types.cpp
simpleProduct.lib  ------- my static library.
and others...
```

but the thing is when ever i used the simpleProduct.h, and call simpleproduct function like this

```
real32_T value=simpleproduct(10,10);
```

it gives me this error. even adding the .lib file for the linker.  why is this happening?

```
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "float __cdecl simpleProduct(float,float)" (?simpleProduct@@YAMMM@Z) referenced in function main  c:\Users\serakpc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\matlabCoder\debugger\Source.obj  debugger
```

plus i would appreciate if someone help me on configuring matlab coder for windows OS generic PC.  for example what do u recommend me to use for the "code replacement library" and "devise vendor" under Hardware Panel

Comment: It is possible that (10,10) in your call is treated as integers and the compiler is looking for a function which takes integers. Try casting this to float explicitly or use 10.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is , check generate matlab code only and create a static project from scratch and compiling the generated code using visual c++. i find this solution in some forums and it works. i think matlab compiles the libraries for linux.

Comment: is it work with Visual C++ compiler only? I have MinGW64 Compiler and get the same error!